# VSCode terminal clips the top of each line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running vscode

Version 1.17.2
Commit b813d12980308015bcd2b3a2f6efa5c810c33ba5
Date 2017-10-16T13:57:00.652Z
Shell 1.7.7
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64

on Korora (Fedora) 25 using xfce

Everything is fine except the text display in a terminal window.  The text is cut off as if the line height is set to 80% of what is needed.  I tried to copy some output but it renders correctly.

No amount of changing

```
"terminal.integrated.lineHeight": 2,
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12  ,
```

seems to help.  Suggestions?  Does anyone else have this issue?

Thanks